# Copy table from On premises SQL server to AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, amazon-rds

I need to copy a SQL server table from an on prem DB to AWS RDS(sql server). I'm trying to think of the simplest way to do that. I was thinking of using a link server to access AWS sql from the on prem DB but not sure how to create one. Or should I go with other option like SSIS or bulk copy.

Comment: If this one time copy and SQL Server TCP port is opened, perhaps simple Export/Import Data Wizard is an option. It can be found in SSMS, if you right click on an on prem database

Comment: it needs to occur daily.

Comment: Consider then a SSIS package. It can be natively scheduled via SQL Agent and will be powered by SSIS catalog, therefore logging, configuration, versioning is out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, there are various ways of doing this on prem to RDS migration!

**Linked Servers** can be used for only EC2 SQL Server instance to RDS SQL Server instance for now I think. The detailed information is here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/

**DMS** can be used to migrate from on prem to RDS:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-ongoing-replication-from-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-using-aws-database-migration-service/

Another solution is to do a periodic **native SQL Server backup** from on prem and **restore** the db onto SQL Server instances: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Or you can migrate by using **transaction logs**: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-migrate-to-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-using-transactional-replication/